# Django wishlist feature implementing

Tags: python, django

I want to do dynamic icon in the CourseListView in the template to show different icons to change color if Course object in a wishlist, but I don't know how to do loop to fetch data, for example (if course in wishlist.objects.all)

models

```
class Wishlist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    wished_course = models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
    added_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views

```
def add_to_wishlist(request,slug):
    course = get_object_or_404(Course,slug=slug)
    wished_course,created = Wishlist.objects.get_or_create(wished_course=course,slug=course.slug,user=request.user,)
    return redirect('courses:courses')

class WishListView(ListView):
    model = Wishlist
    template_name = 'courses/wishlist.html'
    paginate_by = 10
    context_object_name = 'wishlist'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Wishlist.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

class CourseListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Course
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'courses/my_courses.html'
    context_object_name = 'mygroups'

    def get_queryset(self,**kwargs):
        user = get_object_or_404(CustomUser,username=self.request.user.username)
        return user.tutor_courses.all()
```

template

```
     <div class="card">
      <a href="{% url 'courses:course_detail' course.slug %}">
        <div class="blurring dimmable image">
            {% if course.image %}
            <img src="{{course.image.url}}" style="height: 200px; width: 100%;">
            {% else %}
            <img src="{% static 'img/image.png' %}" style="height: 200px; width: 100%;">
            {% endif %}
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="content">
        <a class="header" href="{% url 'courses:course_detail' course %}">{{course.title}}</a>
        <a class="header right floated">${{course.price}}</a>
      </div>
      <div class="extra content">
        <span class="right floated like">
          <a href="{{path}}"><i class="{{color}} like icon"></i></a>
        </span>
        <div class="ui star rating left floated"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="extra content">
          <div class="right floated author">
            <a href="{% url 'users:tutor_profile_view' course.tutor.username %}">
              <img class="ui avatar image" src="{{course.tutor.profile.get_picture}}">  
              {{course.tutor.username}}
            </a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

models

```
class Wishlist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    wished_course = models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
    added_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    #update your model
    def serialize(self):
        return{
           "id": self.wished_course.id,
           "slug": self.slug
        }
```

views
update your view with the code below

```
from django.http import  JsonResponse

def get_wishlists(request, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = Wishlist.objects.all()
    wishlist = [x.serialize() for x in qs]
    data = {
        "response": wishlist
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

urls

update your urlpatterns with the code below

```
path('get-wishlists/', get_wishlists, name='get-wishlists'),
```

template

add this within your loop and update "href" to your addwishilist url

```
<a href="#" id="wished{{course.id}}">
 <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
</a>
```

add this below your template.html file

```
<script>
var user = '{{request.user}}'

if (user != 'AnonymousUser') {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    const method = 'GET'
    const url = '/get-wishlists/'
    const responseType = "json"
    xhr.responseType = responseType
    xhr.open(method, url)
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var serverResponse = xhr.response
        const listedItems = serverResponse.response
        for (var i = 0; i < listedItems.length; i++) {
            var listObj = listedItems[i]
            var tId = listObj.id
            document.getElementById('wished' + tId).innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-heart'></i>"
        }
    }
    xhr.send()
}
</script>
```